# Download Google Photos album continuously

Tags: google-photos

How can I download one of my Google Photos albums and keep it in sync whenever the album changes? There's no need to synchronise in the other direction (upload when local folder changes), but I wouldn't mind.

I've tried to find any option in Backup And Sync to help me achieve part of this, but to no success. I'm running Windows 10. My goal is to point a screensaver to the local folder.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Why you don't want to use Backup and Sync?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for being unclear, I'd be very happy if this could be solved with Backup And Sync. I already use it to sync most of my Drive. I couldn't find any option to sync my Photos at all, just one to upload photos automatically.

Comment: It looks that there isn't a built-in option to do that directly from Google Photos but I'm not 100% sure. Let see if someone else could confirm, or even better, give the answser that you are expecting.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I don't think my comment qualifies as a full-blown "answer".